# HTML create two divs side by side with different heights

Tags: html, css

I want to create two divs side by side with HTML. They should be the same width, and both should have a border. However, I want the boxes to be as long as they need, ie. adapt to how much text is written in them. So one box will be longer than the other.

I tried this code but the divs have the same height and doesn't change based on the text. Any idea of what I could do to fix it?

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
<div style="display: table-row;">
<div style="width: 50%; height; float; display: table-cell; background:white; color:gray; border: dotted 5px; border-color:red">
Div 1
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell; background:green; color:white; padding:20px; border: dotted 5px;; border-color:blue">
Div 2
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use CSS-tables,

Comment: https://learnlayout.com/

Comment: Okey, what should I use instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must assign a Specified amount to width of div for example 300 pixels. Then change second div's display to flexbox .check below

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="width: 300px; display: table-cell; background:white; color:gray; border: dotted 5px; border-color:red">
                some text
            </div>
            <div style="width: 300px; display: flexbox; background:green; color:white; border: dotted 5px;; border-color:blue">
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```